# how to get values from gridview in asp.net web forms?

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview

hello all i am new to asp.net and i want to get values from grid view when i click on Edit or Delete or  and i don't know how to do it i am sending data table to show table data and i don't want to use SQL Data Source from Visual tool box.

i have tried the following code but it gives error

```
     protected void dgv1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {
            int rowindex = ((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
            dgv1.EditIndex = rowindex;
            dgv1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

my view page code is as follows

```
 <form id="form1" class="form-control form-group" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddCustomers" runat="server" Height="376px">
        <asp:Label ID="lblAddCustomers" runat="server" Text="Add Customers"></asp:Label>
        <br  runat="server"/>
        <asp:Label ID="labelAddName" Text="Customer Name" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtboxcustomername"  runat="server" Height="16px"></asp:TextBox>


        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=" Customer City "></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtboxcity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=" Customer Telephone  "></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtboxtelephone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Customers" Height="57px" Width="208px" OnClick="Button1_Click" />


    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="PnlViewCustomers" CssClass="table-dark" runat="server" Height="408px" >
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="dgv1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" EnableTheming="True" PageSize="5" Width="100%" OnRowCommand="dgv1_RowCommand">
            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
        </asp:GridView>

    </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

and body pic is as follow
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5tWA.png)

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LinkButton lnkBtn = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;    // the button
GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)lnkBtn.Parent.Parent;    // the row
```

You may also get the data key index by adding DataKeyNames="MyTableKeyID" to the <asp:GridView /> tab, then

```
string selectedKeyIndex = this.GridView1.DataKeys[myRow.RowIndex]["MyTableKeyID"].ToString();
```